# renderRoutes and the location property on <Switch>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

I'm trying to use the [react-transition-group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group) library for page transition in an app using [react-router-config](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config).

For [react-transition-group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group) to work, I need to add a location property on `<Switch>`, like so:

`<Switch location={location}>`

However, since there is no `<Switch>` when using the [react-router-config](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config) syntax, I am a bit lost. Any suggestions?

There is a discussion on the matter [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/5752) and [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/commit/d1071993e6262bc2e752c79b52a445979ce67111), but no solution yet it seems.

My current component looks like this and the transition works buggy.

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const currentKey = this.props.location.pathname;
        const timeout = 2000;
        return (
            <div>
                <TransitionGroup component="main" className="page-main">
                    <CSSTransition
                        key={currentKey}
                        timeout={timeout}
                        classNames="fade"
                        mountOnEnter={true}
                        unmountOnExit={true}
                        appear
                    >
                        {renderRoutes(this.props.route.routes)}
                    </CSSTransition>
                </TransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{renderRoutes(this.props.route.routes, null, {
    location: this.props.location
})}
```

This is the answer. However, currently **this only works with the latest version of react-router-config**, which is [available from GitHub](https://github.com/JounQin/modules/tree/react-router-config), but not from NPM. I had the NPM version and what the official react-router-config documentation was suggesting would only give me an error.

```
renderRoutes(routes, extraProps = {}, switchProps = {})
```

Now things like react-transition-group seem to work fine.